# I am planning on a sight seeing trip in China during this summer, How can I keep my passport, wallet, and phone safe without overheating?

Tags: safety, china, security, weather-and-climate

TLDR: When it's hot as hell, what's the best way to keep my passport, wallet, and keys ultra secure while keeping my decoy wallet, phone, and some folded papers relatively secure?

Something I could strap to my thigh or my chest would be the best, but I haven't found such a thing. Another option would be wearing a small backpack on my front.

I traveled to China last winter, and I am planning my 2nd trip this summer. I am so excited.

In the winter, I got a taste of how easy things get stolen in China. I helplessly watched a guy get his bag knifed open by a guy and 4 helpers. My tour guide said I absolutely could not interfere. I guess it was for my own safety. I later got my cell phone pick pocketed after putting it in my pocket for 20 seconds to blow my nose. Thank god I had my ultra valuables (passport, wallet) on the inside pocket of my coat.

However now that it is summer, what solutions are there to carrying my passport, wallet, and smart phone without getting them stolen? Putting them on the inside of a coat isn't going to be an option due to the intense heat.

Something lightweight and breathable that goes on the inside would be ideal.

This is the closet thing I've found: http://shop.eaglecreek.com/undercover-neck-wallet/d/1128

I might just go with two of those: One for the inside and one for the outside.

Comment: What you found looks fine. Any small bag you can wear around your neck and put under your T-shirt will do. That is what I used to do. More importantly, get the habit of ALWAYS knowing where your things are. For example, keeping the money under your shirt the entire day and then putting the bag down next to you while you count the change is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Having lived in China for seven years, I have to say crime is not common here. However, there are certain places that are noted for crime. For example Xi'an has a bad reputation and I know several people who have lost money and cameras in that city. Xi'an is also a major tourist destination which exacerbates things.

Generally people who lost things elsewhere did so through carelessness. For example, leaving a cellphone on the table when going to the rest room, come back and it's gone. Oh, and it will be gone. Don't think you might be lucky/unlucky. Leave something unattended and it will go.

Last year I got two pairs of boxer shorts which have zipped pockets on them. I can safely keep money inside those pockets because you literally have to remove my trousers to get into them. However, not the most convenient thing when shopping.